# I got 400 response error, what can I do for it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger

I am working with MVC structure on .NET Core. I have a POST method called `Register` inside my API Controllers.

```cs
[HttpPost("Register")]
        public IActionResult Register(UserDTO userDTO)
        {
            var user = _userService.GetById(x => x.Email == userDTO.Email);
            if (user.Success && user.Data != null)// İşlem Başarısızsa
            {
                return BadRequest("Bu mail adresiyle bir kayıt mevcut.");
            }
            {
                var password = "SVP-" + userDTO.FirstName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Split("-")[0] + userDTO.LastName.ToCharArray()[2]; ;
                byte[] passwordHash, passwordSalt;
                HashingHelper.CreatePasswordHash(password, out passwordHash, out passwordSalt);
                userDTO.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                userDTO.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
                userDTO.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
                //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userDTO);
                //userDTO.ToJson();

                var result = _userService.Add(_mapper.Map<User>(userDTO));
                if (result.Success)
                {
                    _userRoleService.Add(new UserRole
                    {
                        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                        UserId = result.Data.Id,
                        RoleId = (int)userDTO.RoleId!
                    });
                    return Ok(result);
                }

                return Ok(result);
            }
        }
```

When trying to register to the system with this method via Swagger UI, it throws a 400 error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the error it sounds like the system is failing to deserialize the object, specifically the `byte[]` property.  But this leads to a different question... Why is the *client* providing the *hash and salt* for the hashed password?  The *server* should really be defining those things.  If the client provides already-hashed passwords then there's little point in hashing, it's just a password like any other (just one that's difficult to remember).  Providing the "creation date" is equally strange, that's also generally something the server would define.  Etc.  Etc.